# show count and top_categories in the homepage

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I want to show top_categories in the homepage. I have written top_categories function to list the categories that has most number of products. But I have written this function in Product Model. I am confused on where should I write this. Here is my code

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True,
                            blank=False, null=False)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='products')

    def top_categories(self):
        product = Product.objects.values('id').annotate(
            categories_count=models.Count('categories')).order_by('-categories_count')
        return product

def home(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    companies = Company.objects.all()[:12]
    context = {
        'categories': categories,
        'companies': companies
    }
    return render(request, 'company/home.html', context)
```

Now there is a confusion, Do I have to implement top_categories function in Category modal or the way I am doing is fine? Because the job of showing the content in homepage is the role of home view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in **views.py**

```
def home(request):
    # arrange your category on basis of product_count
    categories = Category.objects.annotate(product_count = Count('products')).order_by('-product_count')
    # if you want only top 10 categories
    # categories = categories[:10]
    companies = Company.objects.all()[:12]
    context = {
        'categories': categories,
        'companies': companies
    }
    return render(request, 'company/home.html', context)
```

In **home.html**

```
{% for category in categories %} 
    <h3> category name:</h3>{{category.name}}
    <h3> Total product::</h3>{{category.product_count}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @milan, This should work fine for you. Give it a try and  let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but it says there is no field called 'product'

Comment: @milan, It should be `products` instead of `product` coz of related name you have used. I have updated my answer. It should work now. Have a look.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can you give me an idea if I have to do the logic in models how should i show it in template? I have heard that views should be thin

Comment: But I think this type of thing should not be done in **models.py** and it becomes tedious as it is result oriented things and should be handled in **views** only coz for doing it in model you need to overwrite model mangaers and it is a tedious thing.

Comment: @milan, If my solution helped you, then please upvote and select my answer. Thanks for cooperation.

Comment: @milan, Is it okay now, whatever I explained??

Answer (score 0):

Well think I would do something like this :

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    @staticmethod
    def top_category():
        return models.Count('categories')).order_by('-categories_count')
```

Made it a static method cause it's not about an instance. An even better way of doing it would be to extends the Category manager and add a method `get_top_category` to it so you can call a `Category.objects.get_top_category()`. Then just call it in your Product model :

```
   def top_products(self):
        count_category = Category.top_category() # or Category.objects.get_top_category() if you have done it this way
        product = Product.objects.values('id').annotate(count_category)
        return product
```

Some [doc to override managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Sorry, this one I could not connect well between top_category and top_products and views.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to using templatetags, because if you handle this case with `views` you will create similiar popular filter for another page.

```
# yourapp/templatetags/popcategories.py

from django import template
from yourapp.models import (Category, Product)

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag
def popular_categories():
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    get_total = lambda c: Product.objects.filter(categories__slug=c.slug).count()
    tags_list = [{'category': category, 'total': get_total(category)} for category in categories]
    tags_list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x['total']), reverse=True)
    return tags_list[:10] # return 10 top
```

And then, you can use it in your template `company/home.html` with;

```
{% load popcategories %}
{% popular_categories as categories_list %}
{% for category in categories_list %}
  <a href="">
    {{ category.name }} - {{ category.slug }}
  </a>
{% empty %}
  <p>No categories yet!</p>
{% endfor %}
```